# oauth2client.contrib.flask_util library

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, google-authentication

I have a problem with oauth2client.contrib.flask_util

I create app.config:

```
app.config['GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE'] = 'web_aplication.json'

oauth2 = UserOAuth2(app)
```

and enforced authorization with @oauth2.required

```
@app.route('/example')
@oauth2.required
def example():
    return 'all done'
```

But when I go to web I have a

> Error 400 Error: redirect_uri_mismatch The redirect URI in the request, http://127.0.0.1:5000/oauth2callback, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.

Of course I added `http[s]://[your-app-url]/oauth2callback` to console.cloud.google.com

So my question is how can I route a wrong `http://127.0.0.1:5000/oauth2callback` to `https://[my_url]/oauth2callback`

Answer (score 2):

I haven't fully understood your question. Here are my assumptions:

#### You are testing on your local machine.

In this case, you did visit `http://127.0.0.1:5000/example`, and it redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/oauth2callback` which is absolutely correct. You should add `http://127.0.0.1:5000/oauth2callback` to your Google Cloud console for testing.

#### You are running a production server.

In this case, there must be something wrong with your server configuration, that `url_for` can't make a correct URI.

For your information, the `redirect_uri` is generated by https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/contrib/flask_util.py#L348